# Python to retrieve Outlook email user profile

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

Is there a way to read the Outlook user's profile information, for example job title, Department, telephone number, and reporting manager,  by given an email address?

For example, I have 5 email address (internal user in the same company)

I want to quickly find out above information of each email user (probably with win32com?)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following code.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd 
# Outlook stuff
outApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
outGAL = outApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = outGAL.AddressEntries
data_set = list()

# Iterates through your contact book and extracts/appends them to a list
for entry in entries:
    if entry.Type == "EX":
        user = entry.GetExchangeUser()
        if user is not None:
            if len(user.FirstName) > 0 or len(user.LastName) > 0:
                row = list()
                row.append(user.FirstName)
                row.append(user.LastName)
                row.append(user.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                row.append(user.Department)
                row.append(user.BusinessTelephoneNumber)
                row.append(user.MobileTelephoneNumber)
                row.append(user.CompanyName)
                row.append(user.Name)
                row.append(user.JobTitle)
                row.append(user.OfficeLocation)
                row.append(user.Alias)
                row.append(user.City)
                row.append(user.Comments)
                row.append(user.StateOrProvince)
                row.append(user.StreetAddress)
                data_set.append(row)
first,second,email,dept,office,mobile,company,outlook_name,title,location,alias,city,state,postal = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

for ea in data_set:
    first.append(ea[0])
    second.append(ea[1])
    email.append(ea[2])
    dept.append(ea[3])
    office.append(ea[4])
    mobile.append(ea[5])
    company.append(ea[6])
    outlook_name.append(ea[7])
    title.append(ea[8])
    location.append(ea[9])
    alias.append(ea[10])
    city.append(ea[11])
    
    state.append(ea[13])
    postal.append(ea[14])
address = pd.DataFrame()

address['Full Name']= outlook_name
address['email']=email
address['Department'] = dept
address['Office No.']=office
address['Mobile No.'] = mobile
address['Company']=company
address['City'] = city
address['Title']= title
address['Office']= location
address['Alias'] = alias
address['First Name']=first
address['Last Name']=second
address['Province'] =state
address['Postal Address'] = postal
address.to_excel('Address_book with '+str(address.shape[0])+' contacts.xlsx',index=None,freeze_panes =(1,0))
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a way that it reads a list of given email (instead of reading the whole address book)?

Comment: `for email in email_list:
    recipient = outlook.Session.CreateRecipient(email)
    if recipient.Resolve():
        user = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
        if user:
            print(f"Name: {user.Name}, Email Address: {user.PrimarySmtpAddress}, Job Title: {user.JobTitle}, Department: {user.Department}")
        else:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sequence of actions in the Outlook object model:

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetContact()
```

The [ContactItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.ContactItem) class provides all the required properties you are interested in.

To get an instance of the `Recipient` class you need to use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm760)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) method of the `Namespace` class. For example, a sample VBA macro which shows how to use the method:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") ' or email address
 myRecipient.Resolve
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
 Dim CalendarFolder As Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _ 
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _ 
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! May I know, if there's a way to integrate above in Python codes?